# Storing a list of strings and arrays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is this a smart way of doing this?

So I'm making a class within my class called bankItemList and inside of that I have a string and an int.

```
public List<bankItemList> listOfBankItems = new List<bankItemList>();
[Serializable]
public class bankItemList
{
    public int Stacks;
    public string Name;
    public bankItemList(string name, int amm)
    {
        Name = name;
        Stacks = amm;
    }
}
```

I then use a small function to add items to the List.

```
public bool addItemToBankArray(string name, int amm)
{
    foreach (bankItemList i in listOfBankItems)
    {
        if (i.Name == name)
        {
            i.Stacks += amm;
            return true;
        }
    }
    bankItemList item = new bankItemList(name, amm);
    listOfBankItems.Add(item);
    return true;
}
```

Then I use another function for removing the items.

```
public void bankItemClicked(GameObject obj)
{
        listOfBankItems.RemoveAt(bankitems.IndexOf(obj));
        bankitems.Remove(obj);
        Destroy(obj);
}
```

Of course this is trimmed down to only the core functionality. What I'm mainly asking, is creating a serializable class and adding that class to a list a good way of storing a string and an int that is "related" to each other.

Comment: Is `bankItemList` a child class? Because you cannot define `listOfBankItems` outside of a class.  c# is not c/c++

Comment: WEll the code works 100% fine, i have no issues with having it workign. Im just askign if how i did it is a good way of doing it. And it is a class created within a class. public class UImanager  { [Serializable]
    public class bankItemList
    {}}

Comment: Use UpperCase as starting letter for classes and methods.

Comment: @Sniffle6 you can post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you are doing.  It is the whole point of `[Serializable]`

Comment: thanks @DDave i wasnt aware of that section, sorry

Comment: @Sniffle6 cheers buddy!

Comment: @Sniffle6 The only issue I see with this implementation would be in regards to the `Add` and `Remove` functions being **Linear in Time**. To improve upon time, a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` would possibly be a better option for the case that your data sets become large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine. Just few things needs to be changed. Start naming classes/scripts with the first letter capitalized. Your `bankItemList` should be `BankItemList`.

**IMPORTANT**:

You have to change the `foreach` loop to `for` loop. Don't use `foreach` to loop over `Lists` in the current version Unity. It allocates memory in each loop and the performance is bad.

Your new fixed `addItemToBankArray` function:

```
public bool `addItemToBankArray`(string name, int amm)
{
    for (int i =0; i<listOfBankItems.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (listOfBankItems[i].Name == name)
        {
            listOfBankItems[i].Stacks += amm;
            return true;
        }
    }

    bankItemList item = new bankItemList(name, amm);
    listOfBankItems.Add(item);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sniffle6 Some guy modified your question and messed up the function name which is not valid. Then changed the tag from C# to C#4 but unity doesn't use C#4. I rolled the edit back to your original question.

Comment: you missed that `addItemToBankArray(string, int)` always returns true. IMO a return value is unnessesary, it should be void. also @Sniffle6

Comment: @yes I noticed that. Since he said in his question that he trimmed down to only the core functionality, I believe he left a condition that returns false out.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put all the logic for storing the BankItem objects in your own collection class. That's probably better than having helper methods and another `List` just floating around. It's better to encapsulate all that together into one class.

```
public class BankItem
{
    public int Stacks { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BankItem(string name, int stacks)
    {
        Name = name;
        Stacks = stacks;
    }
}

public class BankItemList
{
    private List<BankItem> bankItems = new List<BankItem>();

    public void AddItem(string name, int stacks)
    {
        BankItem i = bankItems.FirstOrDefault(bi => bi.Name == name);

        if(i != null)
            i.Stacks += stacks;
        else
            bankItems.Add(new BankItem(name, stacks));
    }

    public void RemoveItem(BankItem i)
    {
        bankItems.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a good idea, i have a bad habit of putting too many things in the same class

Comment: I agree with putting it a new class. Few notes: If you are going to serialize it, you have to remove `{ get; set; }` from this answer. Unity can't serialize that. Also linqs make code shorter but they allocate memory too. `bankItems.FirstOrDefault(bi => bi.Name == name);` You are better of sticking with `for` loops on this.